# Maven Unable to deploy from within Eclipse (Mars)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm new to maven, but I have been able to figure out enough to be able to build and deploy my application from the command line with the following command:

mvn clean dependency:tree tomcat6:undeploy tomcat6:deploy

Running this command, builds and deploys my application without issue.

When I attempt to run the same command from within Eclipse (Mars),  I get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- tomcat6-maven-plugin:2.2:undeploy (default-cli) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Undeploying application at http://localhost:8080/myapp-2.3.4-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] Tomcat return http status error: 401, Reason Phrase: Unauthorized
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I suspect that the issue is because outside of Eclipse on I'm not using the same instance of tomcat or something...

Note:  I have two instances of tomcat running on my box within eclipse for development/integrated with Eclipse(port 8080), and external/stand alone(9080).

pom.xml includes:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/myapp-2.3.4-SNAPSHOT</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

maven settings.xml includes:

```
<server>
  <id>TomcatServer</id>
  <username>tomcat</username>
  <password>tomcat</password>
</server>
```

And I've copied the contents of 
$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml

to
$ECLIPSE_WORKSAPACE_DIR/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager,admin,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: You should authenticate.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear - when you run the commands via the command line are you running tomcat inside eclipse or outside eclipse? Also, which version of tomcat are you using?

Comment: I start the server in Eclipse on port 8080, and then run the mvn tomcat6:undeploy tomcat6:deploy from the command line.  When I do this I can monitor the console log inside eclipse and see that the tomcat in Eclipse is updated successfully.  I am using tomcat 6.  Not my decision, just arrived on the poject.